# Cannot connect to wi-fi with AR5BWB222 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, atheros

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04, and am using an Atheros wireless card (AR5BWB222). I find that I can see networks, but cannot connect to any of them. Attempting to do so leads to about 30 seconds of attempting to connect, following by a message telling me that I have been disconnected. I have no backup network connection and cannot therefore run any `sudo apt-get` commands, although I can transfer files very slowly by loading Windows 8 and saving files to another partition (I cannot use a USB stick as only my two USB 3.0 ports appear to be recognized by Ubuntu, both of which I need for mouse/keyboard). `lsmod` tells me that ath9k is in use, but fixes related to using `usehwcrypt=0` have had no effect. `rfkill` shows no hard or soft block. I will happily post any and all relevant diagnostic information, of course.

I apologize if I am repeating an already known bug, but my searches elsewhere have not given me any working solutions. This is particularly problematic as I need to install the wireless to be able to run boot-repair before I can even boot into the right partition to begin fixing my problems with the USB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is partially solved. I have found that, if I *enable* IOMMU in my BIOS, the wireless and USB 2.0 ports start working - but the USB 3.0 ports stop working. A little frustrating, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

What I have personally done to create my networks is the following (though I have done this with fixed ethernet rather than wireless connections - I am guessing it works the same):

- Firstly, remember that ifconfig = fixed connections, and iwconfig = wireless connections, so you won't see wireless connection information with the ifconfig command
- Next, if you have the GUI / desktop installed, use the UI menu item (top right corner drop down menu) to create a new network connection ... select the correct MAC address, and then choose your DHCP or static settings etc.
- sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
- edit the last line after [ifupdown] to managed = true
- this is only one approach, but it is basically choosing to use one set of management tools over another (I believe)
- Next: sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
- and if there is a connection there for your wlan0 (or whatever the connection is called - for mine it is of course eth0), which says something like: #iface wlan0 inet dhcp, and you wanted to set a static address ... then you comment out that line
- Finally, if you are getting the error message about the avahi-daemon not liking your .local domain, you just edit as follows:
- sudo nano /etc/default/avahi-daemon
- change or add > AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0

Now reboot ... you should be able to connect to your fixed or wireless connections ... apologies if this is only for fixed, I don't remember reading that part (though I think I did manage to get it to work for a wireless connection, that was a while ago, let me know how you go)

**One other alternative I saw involved downloading tools:**

- sudo apt-get install wireless-tools

... but I didn't go down that path, so you would have to google that one yourself.

Good luck !

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have had no effect - I can still see the relevant networks, and `iwconfig` shows that I have a `wlan0`, but I am unable to connect to any of them (still instant disconnection). As for wireless tools, since I have no internet connection I'm afraid that I am unable use `sudo apt-get`.

Comment: were there any other config files you touched along the way?

Comment: Also, Can you pinch an ethernet card from somewhere else temporarily just to get a connection & help you fix it?

Comment: sorry, I am a relative newbie too ... so if that didn't work, not sure what else to offer as advice ... perhaps someone else will have some ideas (?)

Comment: Unfortunately I really am locked in, internet-wise - I'm stuck with wifi or nothing at this point. I was as careful as possible to not mess with anything else - at this point I may just try another distro and pray!

Comment: LOL ... the first part of that solution may possibly work, but save yourself the bother on the 2nd part ;-) 

but before you do ... just out of curiosity ... what do you see when you click the network icon in the top right corner of the desktop? you do not even see your connection listed?

Comment: The connection is listed, along with a large number of others - I can try to connect, and it even recognizes that it's encrypted and asks for the password. However, once I supply the password it just spends 30 seconds or so trying to connect then fails, saying "Disconnected".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10577/discussion-between-skipsh-and-mr-president)

Comment: not sure how much help I can be ... someone else will answer eventually (or you'll figure it out yourself like I did with my own things) ... one thing that I found really helped when I was trying to get help on my own problems, was to write extremely detailed steps of what I had done, what I was aiming for, what I was working with etc etc ... because not only will this help others solve the issue, but it helped me narrow down what the next thing I could try was (which I would then add to my question as an update) ... and eventually, the last piece of the puzzle just fell into place :-)